# How to properly texture a character? (Frog Skin)

Tags: texturing

I can't figure out how to texture the character. In blender, it is possible to draw on the UV scan, but I understand that detailed textures are not created in this way. I learned about PBR materials, but I don't understand how to draw with them.
Please tell me: do I need to create PBR material from scratch? I need to texture this frog. I didn't find any suitable PBR materials in Quixel Mixer. How and where are they created? How do I start texturing?(The model is needed for the game)
[image]

Comment: In Blender, head over to the *Texturing Workspace*, click the little plus sign in the *Texture Slots* panel on the right side, add a 'Base Color', a 'Roughness', a 'Specular' slot etc. and start painting. All textures are plugged into the principled shader automatically, makes it 'PBR'... Welcome to the World of PBR texturing (sounds fancy, but that's it technically).

Comment: I would say that there are 2 main methods: painting or procedural, and you can mix both. If you decide to paint, you can even use a real frog texture, in that case the Draw > Stencil brush is really convenient, maybe look into Stencil?

Comment: Also you should show a picture of the kind of texture you want to achieve, it will also depend on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay fully procedural, maybe you could try with a *Voronoi* texture (*Distance* output/*3D/Smooth F1/Euclidean*), use it both as the *Base Color* and as a *Bump* map. Also give a bit of *Subsurface Scattering* to your *Principled BSDF* and put the *Specular* at 1, here is what it gives:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are great man.......... <3